# Spring Boot web app FileNotFoundException for mchange-commons-java-0.2.11.jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, filenotfoundexception

I have used Spring Boot before but not for a web app.  I am in very early development phase on this project (I just finished building the entity classes) and i'm facing a strange exception when running the project :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\607337\.m2\repository\com\mchange\c3p0\0.9.5.2\mchange-commons-java-0.2.11.jar (The system cannot find the file specified)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:225) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:155) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:130) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.JreCompat.jarFileNewInstance(JreCompat.java:188) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFileUrlJar.<init>(JarFileUrlJar.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFactory.newInstance(JarFactory.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.process(StandardJarScanner.java:374) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs(StandardJarScanner.java:309) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.doScanClassPath(StandardJarScanner.java:266) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:229) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars(TldScanner.java:262) [tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scan(TldScanner.java:104) [tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.onStartup(JasperInitializer.java:101) [tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5245) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1421) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1411) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_162]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_162]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_162]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_162]
```

Here is my POM.xml (ignore the fact that everything is set to scope compile, I will change that at some point) :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.mdenis</groupId>
<artifactId>LEM2</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<name>Lab Equiment Manager</name>

<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>

     <!--JAVA-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>8.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!--TOMCAT-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--SPRING-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <!--JTDS-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
        <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--HIBERNATE-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.10.Final</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--LOMBOK-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--JSTL-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>7.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <finalName>LabEquipmentManager</finalName>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Something is looking for this file in the wrong folder since it is not in my repository.  Either that or i'm missing a dependency or something like that.  Has anyone seen this before?

****** UPDATE ******

Forgot this detail but the project actually deploys and works properly.  I am able to run code to create entities and what not.  It's more of an informational type of exception but still i would like it to go away!

Thanks!

Comment: Just don’t use c3p0 as a DataSource and also let spring manage the DataSource. JUdging from your dependencies and how you expres them you are trying very hard not to use Spring Boot (as it appears you are working around it).

Comment: honestly wasn't even aware it came with something built in, i'm still very new to spring as a whole and learning as i go for the most part.  I am using this class for a datasource currently : com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource.  What does Spring boot offer to replace it?  I'd be glad to eliminate this error by using something else!

Comment: It isn't spring that comes bundled with something (although Spring Boot defaults to the HikariCP) but it is also the advice of the Hibernate team to use an externally managed `DataSource` in favor of letting Hibernate manage it. But Spring Boot will auto configure the datasource by just adding a couple of properties to your `application.properties`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research i found out that Hikari is actually bundled into Spring Boot.  I removed C3P0 and replaced my ComboPooledDataSource implementation with Hikari's HikariDataSource.  Everything works like a charm and of course the error is gone.

Comment: Don't. Spring Boot will auto configure it by adding the `spring.datasource.*` properties to your `application.properties`. Which is why I mentioned that you are trying very hard NOT to use Spring Boot. Judging by your dependencies, plugins etc. You are basically re doing everything Spring Boot offers you out-of-the-box.

Comment: What would be the alternative to using Spring Boot? Using Spring-MVC? I'm asking because I'm also not very clear on when to use Spring Boot, and what it actually is. So far, the big plus that I found that it offers me is that it has an embedded server that I can use to serve the application from the command line without the need to deploy it in a separate server.

Comment: Spring boot takes care of a lot of "plumbing" for you that you would normally have to code yourself.  One thing i find awesome so far is that you can build a web app using the good ol' main method approach.  And yes, embedding Tomcat into a jar is a huge game changer for me.  It provides a lot of things you would normally have to include yourself and I seem to discover a new awesome thing every day.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are reference the `mchange`  `c3p0` framework in your code but I don't see a reference to that in your `pom` file.

Trying adding this as a dependency in your `pom` file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
    <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Sadly i tried this before and it has no effect.  Weirdly, the file is already in my local Maven repository but in a different folder : C:\Users\607337\.m2\repository\com\mchange\mchange-commons-java\0.2.11

Comment: Actually after some research, it doesn't look like the file it's searching for should be in the folder it's searching for it in. i.e. the Jar file belongs to a library with a different path. Try deleting (or moving) the folder 'C:\Users\607337\.m2\repository\com\mchange\' and build again.

Comment: exactly, the file is there but under C:\Users\607337\.m2\repository\com\mchange\mchange-commons-java\0.2.11.

Comment: Also try to clean your project.

Comment: I ran clean and build about 8 thousand times in Netbeans, is that what you are referring to?

Comment: Yes but did you try deleting the folder above?

Comment: i just deleted the whole mchange folder and hit Download Declared Dependencies in Netbeans, it pulled the exact same folder / file structure again.

Comment: I couldn't find the jar file `mchange-commons-java-0.2.19.jar` under the dependency directory. So I had to add it manually. Problem is, this is just a lazy workaround. Did it help to delete the dependency directory and run the clean task? I would appreciate any insight, why this jar file is missing from the dependency. The version I am using is

`<groupId>com.mchange</groupId>`
`<artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>`
`<version>0.9.5.5</version>`

Comment: I checked different versions of the dependency on the Maven repo, and they are all missing that jar file.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable jar scanning for tomcat in your spring-boot application.properties

`server.tomcat.additional-tld-skip-patterns=*.jar`